# StageXL MouseEvent not working

Tags: dart, stagexl

I'm trying to create a box on canvas that reacts to MouseClick events using Dart and StageXL. My code is as follows:

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;    
import 'package:stagexl/stagexl.dart' as sxl;

void main() {

  var canvas = html.querySelector('#canvas');
  setCanvasFullScreen(canvas);

  var stage = new sxl.Stage(canvas);
  var renderLoop = new sxl.RenderLoop();
  renderLoop.addStage(stage);

  var rect = new sxl.Shape();
  rect.graphics.rect(80, 50, 100, 100);
  rect.graphics.fillColor(sxl.Color.Crimson);

//  rect.on(sxl.MouseEvent.CLICK).listen(react);
  rect.addEventListener(sxl.MouseEvent.CLICK, react);
  stage.addChild(rect);

}//end main

void react(sxl.MouseEvent event){
  var w = html.window;
  w.alert("I'm clicked!");
}//end onClick


void setCanvasFullScreen(canv) {
  var w = html.window;
//  w.alert("Holla!!!");
  int _width = w.innerWidth as int;
  int _height = w.innerHeight as int;
  canv.setAttribute('width', '$_width');
  canv.setAttribute('height', '$_height');
}
```

I've tried both `on(MouseEvent.CLICK).listen(react);` and `addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, react);` without success there is no reaction. I'm using Dart Editor & SDK version 1.8.5 and debugging on the default Dartium browser.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search on the internet I found this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/stagexl&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=false&hideforumtitle=true&hl=en&parenturl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stagexl.org%2Fforum.html#!searchin/stagexl/mouseevent/stagexl/jyH9tGgvrXU/DUHdrZsRQZEJ) on StageXL forum that properly explained why it did not work. So I've changed the line:

```
var rect = new sxl.Shape();
```

to:

```
var rect = new sxl.Sprite();
```

and it reacts nicely. 

Hope this is helpful to someone.